# Drop columns for highest values in final row in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have multiple one column CSV files which I use `pandas` to concatenate and find the mean:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from sys import argv, exit

os.chdir(f'{argv[1]}')
filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.csv')]
comb = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in filenames], axis=1)
comb.columns = [f'Run {i+1}' for i in range(len(comb.columns))]
comb['Mean'] = comb.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
comb.insert(loc=0, column='Epoch', value=[i+1 for i in range(len(comb))])
comb.to_csv(f'{argv[2]}', index=False)
```

Where `argv[1]` is the directory to concatenate and `argv[2]` is where to save the concatenated file. An example input might be:

```
0.6932
0.6605
0.634
0.5904
0.5339
```

And an example output:

```
Epoch   Run 1   Run 2   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5   Mean
1   0.6932  0.6711  0.6687  0.6814  0.6903  0.684856667
2   0.6605  0.6326  0.6423  0.6323  0.6247  0.639423333
3   0.634   0.6003  0.6063  0.5928  0.5786  0.603956667
4   0.5904  0.5604  0.5576  0.5448  0.5276  0.559693333
5   0.5339  0.519   0.5068  0.496   0.4813  0.513653333
```

This is concatenating five one column, five row CSV files.

How can I drop columns from this table which have the highest number for the final row? Say I want to drop two columns, in this case `Run 1` and `Run 2`. A desired output might be:

```
Epoch   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5   Mean
1   0.6687  0.6814  0.6903  0.680133333
2   0.6423  0.6323  0.6247  0.6331
3   0.6063  0.5928  0.5786  0.592566667
4   0.5576  0.5448  0.5276  0.543333333
5   0.5068  0.496   0.4813  0.4947
```

Does `pandas` have a builtin to drop columns based on the value of some row? I'm interested in the final row for a given column and removing the columns with the highest value there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little over-killed:

```
to_drop = (df.filter(like='Run')  # choose only the `Run` columns
             .iloc[-1]            # and the last row
             .nlargest(2)         # two largest cells
             .index               # then the index, i.e. column names
          )

df = df.drop(to_drop, axis=1)
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this _before_ the columns are named? I would just have a 5x5 table in this case: epoch and mean columns not added, headers not added.

Comment: That's even easier, just drop `.filter(...)`, i.e., `df.iloc[-1]....`

Comment: This worked! I had to name the columns then do the removal, then name the columns again for it to work, however. Without a header, every column is named `0`, so when this finds the columns to remove, it removes all of them because they have the same name.